# meaning of the matrix elements $a_{ij} = 1/i j$ and how to operate them

Tags: linear-algebra

I have this problem: A N-dimensional square matrix with elements $a_{ij} = \frac{1}{i \cdot j}$ and a N-dimensional square matrix B with elements $b_{kl} = \frac{k}{l}$ are used to consecutively transform the vector $\mathbf{\nu} = \sum^N_{j=1}e_i$, where $e_i$ are the basis vectors, into a new vector $\mathbf{u} = \sum^N_{p=1}u_pe_p$.

I understand that by multiplying the two matrices A and B to the vector $\nu$ one can get vector $u$, however, I'm having hard time to deal with the matrix elements of the two matrices, do they have a special meaning and also how to operate with them in order to obtain u.

Thank you in advanced for you help and guidance

Comment: Are you required to calculate $A v $ and $B v $ ? Furthermore, the basis you use is the canonical one? I mean, is vector $e_p $ such that it has 1 in its $p $-th component and 0 anywhere else?

Comment: The idea is to transform $\nu$ to $u$ and for that you use A and B as the corresponding matrices for this transformation so what I learnt was to multiply A to $\nu$ and the to that you multiplied B and then you get $u$, and yes $e_p$ are the basis for $u$

Comment: So, let's take A first. Were you able to write some elements of this matrix? This will help you to "see the pattern" and will be useful for multiplying afterwards.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. I suggest that you start by working out the answer when $n=1$ and then when $n=2$.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I am not sure of this but let's say A is 2X2 so its elements will be {1 1/2 1/2 1/4} and following that idea the elements for B will be {1 1/2 2 1}. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, matrices $A$ and $B$ has a special form which can be expressed as
$$
A= a\cdot a^T,\quad B=b\cdot a^T
$$ where $$
a=\left(1,\frac12,\frac13,\cdots,\frac1N\right)^T, \quad b=\left(1,2,3,\cdots,N\right)^T.
$$ This expression is called [outer product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_product), and is always of the form $a_{ij} = u_i v_j$ for some $(u_i)_{1\le i\le N}$ and $(v_i)_{1\le i\le N}$. Thus $A$ and $B$ are rank $1$ operators sending $\nu$ to
$$
A\nu = a \  a^T\nu =a\ (a\cdot \nu) =\left(\sum_{i=1}^N \frac1i \right)a,
$$ and
$$
B\nu =b\ a^T  \nu = b\ (a\cdot \nu)=\left(\sum_{i=1}^N \frac1i \right)b.
$$